# Defining State Representation in Deep Q-Learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

So I am having difficulty difficulty figuring out exactly how I want to represent my environment state in my Deep Q-learning problem.

**Premise**: There is a 2D grid space of which an agent needs to visit all the cells (because it is searching the space), once a cell is visited it is considered "searched" and therefore does not need to be visited again.

**First Take**: I thought well what if the state representation of the environment to the agent was just the 8 adjacent cells and their searched/unsearched status. In this case the resulting actions would be to move to one of the adjecent cells. Here we have 2^8 different possible states and then 8 actions for our Q(s,a) function.

Since I am using a DQN structure to the problem, the Q function would be approximated by a neural network with 8 inputs (status of adjacent cells) and 8 outputs (actions). Obviously the reward function would be simple as it yields a high reward for moving to a cell that has not been searched and a low reward otherwise.

However, this presents an obvious problem when all the adjecent cells have been searched. The agent would move randomly and possibly away from cells that need to be searched. This is not good for my purposes.

**Second Take**: I thought if I wanted to work around this I would need to incorporate information about the entire state-space into my Q function. Meaning that the agent knows the status of all cells and has actions that are basically "waypoints" that bring the agent to that cell.

This would make my inputs and outputs to the Q function A LOT larger as I have a really big state-space. I don't have a specific size yet, but it could easily be 10,000 (100x100 grid) or larger. And obviously my reward function would need to reward the agent more for actions that involve less movement.

Also, my problem can be formulated in a simulation to train the Q function, so I'm not worried about training time due to physical constraints.

So basically my question is this:

Can this Q function still be approximated by a neural network of reasonable size? Yes, I have a lot of processing power at my disposal (sorry I know this is all very vague), but I'd rather not blow things out of proportion.

tldr: I have Deep Q-Learning problem where I think I need a large state-action space, and am wondering if it is too large to be reasonably approximated by a neural network.

**Edit**: As @Constantinos noted, I didn't really define my problem well enough, so here are more assumptions and definitions below.

- State-Space:

  - The grid itself is not exactly the state-space, each cell in the grid has a "searched" or "unsearched" status so the total number of unique states that my state-space can take on is really along the lines of 2^10,000 (assuming 100x100 grid).
  - Additionally, the state-space also contains information about the location of the agent.
- Action-Space:

  - At any given position, the agent may move to any other location on the grid. Therefor the action space is simply the 10,000 moves available.
- Reward Function:

  - Positive reward for choosing action that brings agent to unsearched location.
  - Negative reward for choosing action that brings agent to location that is far away (to constrain movement).
  - High positive reward for choosing action that brings the agent to a goal state (i.e. where all locations have been searched).
- I/O of Q-Network:

  - The input will be the a vector of elements (each representing a cell on the grid, can also be seen as an 'image feature' where the image is the grid) that take on values 0 or 1 (unsearched or searched).
- The input will also have to include some embedded information on the agents location (I am currently thinking of just altering the value of the input element that represents the agents location cell to be -1).
- Output of the network will be a vector of action utility values, each representing the utility of moving to a certain grid location.

Lastly, I should note that once an agent visits a location, that location is now considered "searched" and the state of the environment is updated accordingly.

Comment: I don't think an input of state of 100x100 bits and action of 8 bits is too big for an ANN, it is about the amount of data in a small image, which is an common input space size.

Comment: @DavidAriel, Yeah I was thinking that as well. Although I should have noted that with this second method, the actions are also the same size as the statespace (since they represent the waypoints of each cell that can be moved to). 

In this method I would need to feed in the position of the agent as well somehow since it is no longer inherently at the center of the statespace. Do could these just be another input to the neural network, and the network would be able to take this into account and choose actions that favor closer states?

Comment: You do not specify what your reward function is and thus it is really hard to guess if the network can approximate the Q. Also in your first approach you do not state clearly why there is a problem. The agent will explore randomly at the beginning for sure till it will discover the best strategy. The strategy will depend on the function you are trying to optimize with RL: your reward function.

Comment: I am not sure why you need a DQN approach. With 100x100 grid world you can use simple Q-learning which will guarantee to converge (if states are visited enough). In any case you can formulate your features as one-hot-encoding feature images. For example 9x9 (or 100x100) images. One feature image will contain zeros everywhere except the location of the cells that are searched which will contain ones. Another feature image will be everywhere zero except the location of you agent etc. Every time step you will input a bunch of these images to your network.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more more on reward function, rules of the grid world step function (how you transit from cell to cell) and which are your actions.

Comment: @Constantinos, I'll explain my problem a bit more. The grid size is going to be very large but this is not exactly the statespace of my agent. So say I do just use a 100x100 grid (so 10,000 cells). Each of these cells has a status that represents it as "searched" or "unsearched", so in reality the total number of unique states for my statespace is 2^10,000, which is extremely large, hence the need to approximate my Q function. In addition to this the state of my environment will also include the location of the agent (i.e. which cell it's in). My action space is to move to any cell on the grid

Comment: Each time step will consist of the agent looking at the current state of the environment (as described above), choosing an action (choosing a cell to move to), and then moving to that cell. Once the agent has visited the cell it's status has now become "searched". This process then repeats.

The reward function will be as follows: positive reward for choosing a cell to move to that has not been searched, negative reward for choosing a cell to move to that is far away, and a large postive reward for completing the search (i.e. reaching the goal state, where all cells have been searched).

Comment: Additionally, I had planned on using a feature image like approach as the input to my network like you had mentioned.
I hope this explanation made sense.

Comment: From your explanation i do not think you will have a problem. AlphaGo had also a similar configuration with feature images as inputs and the whole board as action space. I am using a NN with around 21 feature images (32x32) navigating in a 32x32 map and 512 possible actions and still learns. The best way to find out is to build your environment and test your algorithm. Start simple. I would go with feature images but later you might examine learning from pixels (i.e black pixels for searched and white for unsearched) but this approach would need some engineering. Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: When you say "feature images" you simply mean using the searched/unsearched statuses of all the locations as the input of the network right for each time step right? I think we are talking about the same thing just calling it different names. Also, thanks for all your help!

Comment: You can use a vectorized approach in which a state is your grid world state transformed into a vector. Then you will use feedforward net approaches. The feature image is a matrix (e.g. 100x100) and you will use convolutional network approaches (to capture spatial relationships between tiles). A feature image might represent your location, so a 100x100 matrix of zeros and one at your location. It might represent searched cells so 100x100 matrix with ones at the location of the searched cells. You feed all these at once to your CNN for every step you make. You are welcome!

Comment: Ahh, I see. That does seem like a much better way to represent my own location and preserve spatial relationships of the statespace. So if I had multiple feature images, which it looks like I will have, do I combine these (100x200) before putting into the CNN? Or is there some temporal aspect to the CNN? Or are there two feature extraction convolutional networks and then one dense network at the end which uses features from both?

Comment: Yes as you say, for every time step you take your feature images that represent your state and you input them to the network as a volume (grid height x grid width x num_of_feats). After for example 2 convolutional layers you can have a fully connected layer to output through a softmax probabilities over locations (you can put a LSTM before that if you want to capture temporal relationships). Or you can use a Convloutional LSTM which according to the original paper it is claimed to perform better and maintaining spatio-temporal relationships.

Comment: Another option is to use a convlolutional layer as output which the result would be an image with the spatial policy from which the actions would be sampled from, but you need to use policy gradients methods here. I suggest you to look at the implementation of the DeepMind's Starcraft II agent. I think you can draw lots of similarities if you want to follow the above approaches. For now I suggest you to start very simple: Deep Q with feature images or vectors and a very small grid world. Check what makes sense and what not. Your action space is quite big so does your net generalizes well etc.

Comment: Thanks again, I think I have a pretty good idea where to start with this project now